# "Move Factory" for c++ 11

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I want to make a factory style generator, which takes in A and outputs a subclass of A, RA (it adds information to A). I can't really think of a safe way to do this though.

structure:

```
class A
{
public:
  std::string str;
  A(std::string a)
  {
    str = a;
  }
  A(A&& a) :
    str(std::move(a.str))
  {
  }
};

class AR : public A
{
public:
  std::string str1;
  AR(std::string a,std::string b) : A(a)
  {
    str1 = b;
  }
  AR(A &&a,const std::string& b)
    : A(std::forward<A>(a))
  {
    str1 = b;
  }
  AR(AR&& ar)
    : A(std::forward<A>(ar)),
    str1(std::move(ar.str1))
  {
  }
};

class ARFactory;
```

The safest way would probably be

```
  AR GenerateRA1(A&& a)
  {
    return AR(std::forward<A>(a),std::string("foo"));
  }
```

which would enforce that a is being destructed. Problem is that this causes the user to not ever to be able to use the argument of a in any way before the function call, which could be annoying:

```
ARFactory fact;
{
  AR ar=fact.GenerateRA1(A("bar"));//compiles
}
{
  A a("bar");
  a.str += "1";
  //AR ar = fact.GenerateRA1(a);//doesn't compile
  AR ar = fact.GenerateRA1(std::move(a));//does...reference to a is still around, but destroyed
  std::cout << "a.str=" << a.str << " b.str=" << ar.str << " ar.str1=" << ar.str1 << std::endl;
}
```

Is this OK? I can see calls to "a" going horribly awry without build in checks to see if the object has been destroyed.

Comment: There are different things wrong with your code that you should understand before trying to get an answer to the question. For example, your constructors unnecessarily create copies when they should be *moving*...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I am more than willing to believe there are things wrong with my code. However, I double checked (by making manual copy constructors with print statements) the copy constructor is never called, only the move constructors, in this code. Can you point to a specific location where it is copied?

Comment: Note that copies can be elided, so even if you trace the copies the copy operation might or not show in your test code. That being said, in each constructor that you do: `X(Y&& y) : member(y) {}` a copy is made from `y` to `member`. You need to force the move: `X(Y&& y) : member(std::move(y)) {}` or copies will be made. Binding an rvalue-reference does not *move* out of the source.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas ah I forgot a std::foreward in the AR create from A constructor. std::foreward should be sufficient in order to call the move constructor though, correct?

Comment: If you want to *move* and the source is an rvalue-reference, why use `std::forward`? Does `std::move` not make it clearer? Also note that in some constructors you still need `std::move`: `A(std::string a) : str(std::move(a)) {}` does not involve copying while your implementation of that constructor **copies**. I'd try to fully understand the basics of what moving is before jumping into more complex situations.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas std::move would cascade move constructors, wile std::forward should just forward the arguments as passed (Move constructors are less intensiveness than copy constructors, but do not come at no cost, why cascade move constructors when forwarding will do what I actually intend?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas as an added problem, using std::move steals the resources at the std::move call, which is problematic in the move constructor because it could steal the parts of the subclass that are not in the super class...while this may not actually happen (because A is not aware of the members of AR to steal them), what i want is a foreward and not a move.

Comment: You have a couple of misconceptions of what `std::move` and `std::forward` do (probably in general, but specifically in this case). In particular all uses of `std::forward` in your code above will yield the same result as `std::move`. `std::move` does **not** steal the resources at the `std::move` call, it means exactly `static_cast<T&&>(x)` and nothing else (i.e. it let's you bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue). Whether that is used to *steal* the contents or not is up to the code that uses the result of `std::move`.

Comment: *Why cascade move constructors when forwarding will do what you intend?* If your intention is moving, then your code does that, it just does not *look* like. If you intention is other, then your code does not do what you intend. There are very little sensible uses (if any at all) of `std::forward` outside of template functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
AR ar = fact.GenerateRA1(std::move(a));//does...reference to a is still around, but destroyed
```

The user **requested** that you *move* the contents out of `a` into the function, she **knows** that the contents of `a` might have been moved and knowing the type `A` she knows what can be done or not with the object `a`. This is **not** a problem, this is how things work.

```
//AR ar = fact.GenerateRA1(a); //doesn't compile
```

This is exactly the main point. The compiler rejects this code, so that the user does not need to *check* whether `a` is moved out of or not (*), only if the user explicitly requests the move (and thus **knows** without having to guess) the compiler will move out of the object.

Comment: Nice, i was just ensuring that this was kosher. Still feels weird, cuz it breaks RAII, even if the end user is explicitly telling me to do it. In general, I'd like to see something from the standard where a block can have an RValue return type without defining lambdas and what not. like '{A a("bar"); a.srt+="1"; breturn a;}" would yield an A&& at the start of the block. Would break a billion other things though, so this is NOT good enough, but its just kinda what I want.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: What's so bad about adding `[]()` in front and `()` after the end of the block?